# Rails 5 Bootstrap 4 how do I turn on bootstrap-variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

I have followed the bootstrap-rubygem setup directions.  Everything works except when I try to access variables like `$black` and `$white` I get a Sass::SyntaxError of Undefined variable.  I've been googling this for the past 4 hours. Is there something that I need to turn on? I used to do this successfully with rails 4.2 and bootstrap 3 years a couple years ago, but now I'm at a loss.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', git: 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  # gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

**application.scss**

```
$body-bg: $black;
@import "bootstrap";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  This is straight from the horse's mouth.  You need to download the `_bootstrap-variables.scss` file from [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/templates/project/_bootstrap-variables.scss) and place it inside `app/assets/stylesheets`.

Uncomment the variables you want to use (e.g. $black, $white, etc.)

Then, `application.scss` should look like:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-variables";

$body-bg: $black;
$body-color: $white;

@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: That link to the bootstrap-variables.scss file is broken :( I get an error 404 when clicking the link.

Comment: Try
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

Comment: Suppose copying the file, rather than referencing, ain't DRY. It'll also obscurely and subtly go out of date.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the variables working in my custom files by using the following manifest file

application.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

As per the bootstrap gem instructions, I had to **remove `require_tree`**, but `require_self` seems to be ok.

With this in place, you have access to `$text-muted` or `$brand-primary` inside custom.scss.

Presumably you can define your custom colors in that file as well.

```
$body-bg:    $black;
$body-color: $white;
```

Or better yet, define a _custom_variables.scss file and import that before your custom css files.

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom_variables";
@import "custom";
```

If you want to redefine the bootstrap variables before bootstrap uses them, then use the order

```
@import "custom_variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

However, be aware that any custom bootstrap sass methods will blow up, (i.e. darken()) unless you import bootstrap first.  So, you can't just import the entire bootstrap variables first. (tried and failed!)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the docs are wrong. If you have the application.scss like so:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

and put

@import bootstrap

at the top of the scss file you compose, you can make things work.

static_pages.sass:

```
// Place all the styles related to the static_pages controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
$body-bg:    green  

@import bootstrap

body > div > p
  color: $red
```

all of that will work. Passing one variable into another though does not seem to work.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:
If you are using scss as the file extention for the static_pages css file the code css markup is a bit different.

```
// Place all the styles related to the static_pages controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
@import 'bootstrap';

// $red: #800000;


p {
  color: $red;
  }
```

If all else fails you can clone [this app](https://github.com/jeremyawhitman/boostrap_4_rails) and it will work.

Comment: I edited the answer with a bit more specifics, and added a git repo to clone that works if you edit the static_pages.scss.

Comment: Basically what I want, is to set `$body-bg: $black`.  If I put this line before the @import it breaks.  If I put it after it doesn't change the background color.  I know I did this with bootstrap 3 somehow but I can't remember.  Like there was some way to override bootstrap variables located here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/templates/project/_bootstrap-variables.scss

Comment: The gem you are using is alpha software, and as far as I can tell the feature you are trying to use does not work at this time. I  have tried every configuration I can think of to get it to work...and no dice for that particular feature...and only to as far as I did by disregarding the docs on github, so the best course of action at this point is probably to ask on the github page for the gem. If you reference this thread, they may get to the bottom of it.